# Golang - gomobile basic script compile error

Tags: java, android, go

Probably that is newbie question, but that takes me 2 days with 0 progress.
I build before Hello Gopher World on my mobile with Android Studio, but when I tried to do that same with 'basic' mobile script from https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/mobile/example/basic
I get that error:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:compileDebugSources, :app:compileDebugAndroidTestSources]
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:hello:gobind
exec: "gcc": executable file not found in %PATH%
C:\gowork\bin\gomobile.exe: go build -p=4 -pkgdir=C:\gowork\pkg\gomobile/pkg_android_arm -tags="" -i -buildmode=c-shared -o=C:\Users\Pablo\AppData\Local\Temp\gomobile-work-627382299\android\src\main\jniLibs\armeabi-v7a\libgojni.so C:\Users\Pablo\AppData\Local\Temp\gomobile-work-627382299\androidlib\main.go failed: exit status 2
# _/C_/Users/Pablo/AppData/Local/Temp/gomobile-work-627382299/go_hello
C:\Users\Pablo\AppData\Local\Temp\gomobile-work-627382299\go_hello\go_hellomain.go:8: imported and not used: "golang.org/x/mobile/bind/seq"
C:\Users\Pablo\AppData\Local\Temp\gomobile-work-627382299\go_hello\go_hellomain.go:9: imported and not used: "golang.org/x/mobile/example/bind/hello"
Error:Execution failed for task ':hello:gobind'.
> Process 'command 'C:/gowork/bin\gomobile.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 8.174 secs
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

That is build.gradle of hello module:

```
plugins {
    id "org.golang.mobile.bind" version "0.2.2"
}

gobind {
    pkg = "golang.org/x/mobile/example/bind/hello"

    GOPATH = "C:/gowork"

    GO = "C:/Go"
}
```

There is go file: (C:\gowork\src\golang.org\x\mobile\example\bind\hello\hello.go)

http://pastebin.com/PPCn6sPE

And (MainActivity)java file from I try to use function main():

http://pastebin.com/61f8pSSb

Comment: Do you have gcc installed?

Comment: I read that is installed with Go 1.5 ? I build working Hello World before on my phone, so probably yes. I can have a bad info too idk.

Comment: No, gcc is not installed with Go. The program complains that it can't find gcc. Make sure that you have it, it's in your PATH, and it's for the right platform.

Comment: Gcc is maybe in NDK ? I no install it, i just installed Git Bash which solve some problems on few days, I was added to path any before "C:\Go".

Comment: I install NDK and i used command: ./make-standalone-toolchain.sh --system=windows --toolchain=arm-linux-androideabi-4.9 --platform=android-9 --install-dir=E:/Code/Android/android-toolchain --ndk-dir=E:/Code/Android/android-ndk-r10e, after that all i was added to PATH: E:\Code\Android\android-toolchain\bin, and is that same error

Comment: I was installed mingw and that was helped

Comment: Have you solved it? If you solved your own problem, [you should post an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) so that other users could find it and upvote you.

Comment: I solved any that line with **exec: "gcc": executable file not found in %PATH%** was dissapear and rest error stay.

Comment: So, you still have an error? Show us the new error. I cannot be the same.

Comment: Here is the error: http://pastebin.com/Cguaebny I Added too gradle of hello module to the mai post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, my fault if somebody will have same problem in feature there somebody explained me:
https://github.com/golang/go/issues/12842

In short I tried to build native Go app.